# Grouping time ranges using time delta?

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with a csv file which details a unique patient and the treatment they underwent during a specific time period. We want to see how many patients underwent  a secondary line of treatment 90 days+ after the first round ended.

Here's a sample:

```
PatientID   TreatmentDate   DrugCode
0   2038    1/24/2010   A
1   2038    1/27/2010   A
2   2038    1/30/2010   A
3   2038    2/2/2010    A
4   2038    2/6/2010    A
5   2038    2/11/2010   A
6   2038    2/18/2010   A
7   2038    2/20/2010   A
8   2120    1/25/2010   A
9   2120    1/25/2010   B
10  2120    1/26/2010   A
11  2120    1/26/2010   B
12  2120    1/27/2010   A
13  2120    1/27/2010   B
14  2120    1/29/2010   A
15  2120    1/29/2010   B
16  2120    2/1/2010    A
17  2120    2/1/2010    B
18  2120    2/4/2010    A
19  2120    2/4/2010    B
```

We can infer that:

1. Rows 0-7 belong to one treatment period for patient 2038
2. Starting on 1/25/2010, patient 2120 started a program using both drugs A&B.

I'm new to Python and I'm struggling a bit whether I should restructure the dataframe itself first, or if there's something elegant that I can do as-is to add a column for treatment period. Would appreciate any help!

Comment: How do you determine if a patient has started treatment round #2? by different drug usage?

Comment: @RockyLi that's the tricky thing - the second round technically could be the same treatment, so I think we just have to assume some significant amount of time delta.

Comment: I think then the answer would be to identify patient that had came in with time difference between successive record spanning more than +90 days? If it is formulated this way, it would be quite straightforward

Comment: Also to isolate that start and ends of those treatment periods

Answer (score 0):

### How many patients underwent a secondary line of treatment 90 days+ after the first round ended?

Well, nobody in this dataset! My approach here is to isolate each patient at a time to make the problem a bit easier. Once I have a `DataFrame` for a patient I add a column with the time shifted so I can another column with the time delta. So with the resulting `patient_df` you could do something like this:

```
from datetime import timedelta
over_ninety = patient_df[patient_df['TimeDelta'] > timedelta(days=90)]
```

I think there is a better way to do this, as there usually is whenever you have loops with Pandas, but this was simple to write. I think Pandas `MultiIndex` might be the way to keep this all in one `DataFrame` or merge the `TimeDelta` column back to the original `DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd

# Leaving out code to create df with your example data set...

for unique_patient in df['PatientID'].unique():
    patient_df = df[df['PatientID'] == unique_patient].copy()
    patient_df['NextDate'] = patient_df['TreatmentDate'].shift(-1)
    patient_df['TimeDelta'] = patient_df['NextDate'] - patient_df['TreatmentDate']
    print(patient_df)

   PatientID TreatmentDate DrugCode   NextDate TimeDelta
0       2038    2010-01-24        A 2010-01-27    3 days
1       2038    2010-01-27        A 2010-01-30    3 days
2       2038    2010-01-30        A 2010-02-02    3 days
3       2038    2010-02-02        A 2010-02-06    4 days
4       2038    2010-02-06        A 2010-02-11    5 days
5       2038    2010-02-11        A 2010-02-18    7 days
6       2038    2010-02-18        A 2010-02-20    2 days
7       2038    2010-02-20        A        NaT       NaT
    PatientID TreatmentDate DrugCode   NextDate TimeDelta
8        2120    2010-01-25        A 2010-01-25    0 days
9        2120    2010-01-25        B 2010-01-26    1 days
10       2120    2010-01-26        A 2010-01-26    0 days
11       2120    2010-01-26        B 2010-01-27    1 days
12       2120    2010-01-27        A 2010-01-27    0 days
13       2120    2010-01-27        B 2010-01-29    2 days
14       2120    2010-01-29        A 2010-01-29    0 days
15       2120    2010-01-29        B 2010-02-01    3 days
16       2120    2010-02-01        A 2010-02-01    0 days
17       2120    2010-02-01        B 2010-02-04    3 days
18       2120    2010-02-04        A 2010-02-04    0 days
19       2120    2010-02-04        B        NaT       NaT
```

Comment: Thank you! This reminds me sort of like using self-joins to mind the max/min of a certain grouping. These are ordered by PatientID and date in the dataset, so I'll fiddle around with this to see how I can then add another column for "TreatmentSet".

Comment: Does this solve your problem? From your question I didn’t see why you would need a TreatmentSet column. Would be happy to add more if you can help me understand what you are after. A clear definition of what constitutes a TreatmentSet would be helpful.

Comment: Ideally to be able to measure the length of the treatment periods and compare first, second, and third. With a TreatmentSet column, I could easily find the start and end dates of these treatment periods.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

# Generate a datetime column
df.dates_formatted = df.apply(lambda x: datetime(x.TreatmentDate.split('/')[2],\
 x.TreatmentDate.split('/')[0], x.TreatmentDate.split('/')[1])

# Generate a difference between each datetime stamp after sort
def get_timediff(df):
    df = df.sort_values('TreatmentDate')
    df.DateDiff = df.TreatmentDate.diff()
    df.DateDiff 
    return df

new_df = df.groupby('PatientID').apply(get_timediff(df))

# Return a series of patientID : True/False
new_df.groupby('PatientID').apply(lambda df: df.DateDiff.max > timedelta(days=90))
```